# How to read two or more word separeted by comma in a line in a CSV file in Java?

Tags: java, csv

Here is my CSV file:

```
11608030,12345  
11608045,54321
```

Here is my code:

```
package csvtest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    private ArrayList<Long> account_number = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Test() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("E:\\account.csv"));

        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            this.account_number.add(Long.parseLong(scanner.next()));
            this.password.add(scanner.next());
        }
        System.out.println(account_number);
    }
}
```

and in the main class there is only one command

`Test test = new Test();`

but when i run this code i got a message like this

> > Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)     at
> >     java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)     at
> >     csvtest.Test.(Test.java:28)     at
> >     csvtest.CSVTest.main(CSVTest.java:21)
> >     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
> >     Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

whats wrong with my code??
need help!!!
thanks in advance :)

Comment: what happens if scanner.next() is null when it is called a second time?

Comment: i dont know,i am fresher in java,
Can u pls help me to modify my code?
i want to read and store first number in account_name ArrayList
and 2nd number in password ArrayList

Comment: You are checking hasNext once, which means you can only be sure of having one more element, but you always read 2 elements with next. If there is only one element, the second one will throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use    `scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\n");` The issue that you originally had was that the second `scanner.next()` read in "12345\n11608045" since you didn't specify that a newline could be a delimiter as well. So when `scanner.next()` was called the last time there wasn't anything to read from since that second call to next() read two of your values.

Answer (score 1):

scanner.next() gets you a line from the file, you then need to split that line into your comma seperated values:

See example:

```
    @Test 
    void parseAccountsCsvFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        ArrayList<Long> account_number = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<String> password = new ArrayList<String>();
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("accountsCsvTest.txt"));
   
           while(scanner.hasNext()){
            String scannerLine = scanner.next();
            String[] values = scannerLine.split(",");
               account_number.add(Long.valueOf(values[0]));
               password.add(values[1]);
           }
           System.out.println(account_number);
           System.out.println(password);
           scanner.close();
       }
   }
```

Output:

> [11608030, 11608045]
>
> [12345, 54321]

I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: This won't compile. The bal() function is missing a return type. ( In the original question as well)

Comment: Well spotted, i didn't the other lines... have updated bal to void, since it seems to set instance variables.

Comment: @AlanBlyth , values[0] is String type, it should be first parsed into Long before adding into account_number list.

Comment: Good point, please forgive my laziness, I made penance by actually creating the csv file and running the code completely to ensure it is complete and correct. Updated Answer.